# Formatting DateTime in Excel XML worksheet

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

When generating an Excel XML workbook with ASP.NET i'm appending 3 cells in a row like:

```
sb.Append(String.Format(
"<Cell><Data ss:Type=\"DateTime\">{1}</Data></Cell>{0}",
Environment.NewLine, 
item.DateAvailable.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffK")
)); // newlines added for readability;
```

`item.DateAvailable` is a C# `DateTime` that has to end in Excel as An cell-DateTime.

so

value from debug in VS2010 in asssembly:

```
 2011-08-15T01:16:06.8470000
```

value in excel:

```
 40761,2299142361
```

after manual conversion of the cell formatting:

```
 6-08-11 5:31
```

However, when converting **it outputs in excel as a number**, and the **cell formatting is set to custom**. When I manually change the cell formatting back to DateTime the correct??? date is shown in the correct format. But of course, the business would not accept such a raw data they have to convert themselves ;)

*Perhaps I am using the wrong StringFormat?*

**What is the correct format to write a DateTime in this case and output it in Excel in the correct DateTime Format?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you are using a "wrong" string format, i.e. a format that Excel does not automatically recognize (or parse appropriately) as a date. Drop the `T`. Also, the date-time format in Excel rounds at least to milliseconds, if not to integer seconds, so you might as well drop some of those decimal places.

This should work:

```
item.DateAvailable.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ffff")
```

Comment: I've found it wouldn't work without the 'T'. ie time.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.ffff") *shrugs*