# XSLT - parse date and time

Tags: excel, xml, xslt

I am attempting to set the Type attribute of a cell in Excel via XSL. It should look at report/sheet/definition/column and see if there's a `type` attribute. If yes, it should set the Cell Type to that type and format it in full time (or datetime) manner.

My xml data:

```xml
<report>
  <sheet>
    <definition>
      <columns>
        <column name="Code" footerText="ISO Code" width="80" />
        <column name="Time" footerText="Time" format="DateTime" width="58" type="DateTime" />
        <column name="Country" footerText="Country" width="100" />
        <column name="SomeNumber" footerText="Country" width="100" type="Number"/>
      </columns>
    </definition>
    <data>
      <table>
        <row>
          <column value="2020-04-02" key="DATE" />
        </row>
        <row>
          <column value="123" />
          <column value="10:30" />
          <column value="Belarus" />
          <column value="0" />
        </row>
        <row>
          <column value="321" />
          <column value="12:00" />
          <column value="Austria" />
          <column value="0" />
        </row>
        <row>
          <column value="2020-04-03" key="DATE" />
        </row>
        <row>
          <column value="456" />
          <column value="08:00" />
          <column value="USA" />
          <column value="24" />
        </row>
      </table>
    </data>
  </sheet>
</report>
```

I have tried printing out $type and $index in the cell and they truly print out properly, but when I try to take the value of `$type` and use for `<xsl:attribute name="ss:Type">`, Excel provides me with an error saying it had problems during the load. After checking out the logs, it turns out that it can't parse values like `12:00` into a Time (or shall I say DateTime?). I have two questions:

1. Is that expected behavior that it can't parse timespan values into DateTime?
2. Is it normal behavior that it can't parse `2020-01-01` as DateTime as well?

```
<xsl:for-each select="data/table/row">
  <ss:Row>
    <xsl:variable name="set" select="column" />
    <xsl:variable name="count" select="count($set)"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="column">
      <ss:Cell>
        <xsl:variable name="index" select="position()"/>
        <xsl:variable name="type" select="../../../definition/columns/column[$index]/@type"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="ss:MergeAcross">
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$count>1">
              <xsl:value-of select="0"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:value-of select="$mergeAcrossHeader"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <ss:Data>
          <xsl:attribute name="ss:Type">
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="$type!=''">
                <xsl:value-of select="$type" />
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:text>String</xsl:text>
              </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:value-of select="@value" />
        </ss:Data>
      </ss:Cell>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </ss:Row>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: add one more `../`as `<xsl:variable name="type" select="../../../../definition/columns/column[$index]/@type"/>`.

Comment: @AmrendraKumar I properly accessed `@type` because I can print its value without issues. It doesn't seem so because I haven't provided the full XSLT template here, which would be redundant, I believe.

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6438689